# Observables or ViewTreeObserver

Tags: java, android

Is there a better way of subscribing to see if a flag has been tripped or layout changed other than using code below?

```
  layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            ....
        }
    });
```

Comment: "Better" depends on what you want to do. What are you trying to do?

Comment: got what i needed using layout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ...
                }
            }
        });